# How to implement unsigned abs(int)?

Tags: c++, c, integer-overflow

So this seems easy but either I'm missing something or... there is no way to do it?..

First try:

```
unsigned abs(int value) { return value < 0 ? -value : value; }
```

Nope, "-value" is an UB. This is detected by clang -fsanitize and is generally unsafe in the face of aggressive optimizations (although I really hope no sane compiler abuses this).

Ok. Let's cast to unsigned!

```
unsigned abs(int value) { return value < 0 ? -unsigned(value) : unsigned(value); }
```

Nope, this results in C4146 warning in MSVC. Additionally due to definition of unary minus on unsigned values I think this assumes a two-complement integer format for signed integers.

Ok...

```
unsigned abs(int value) { return value < 0 ? ~unsigned(value) + 1 : unsigned(value); }
```

This does not seem to generate any warnings or undefined behaviors, but of course only works for two-complement integers. Also, it's kinda obscure - needs a comment that explains why this is not using something straightforward...

Is it actually possible to implement an aforementioned function without triggering UBs or relying on the integer representation? Please tell me the answer is "yes" before I lose all remaining hope in C.

Comment: Are you converting signed integer to unsigned integer or do you need an `abs` function taking `unsigned int` as parameter?

Comment: How about 0-val instead of -val?  `unsigned abs(int value) { return value < 0 ? 0-value : value; }`

Comment: Since `INT_MIN` is an edge case, you could just handle it explicitly. That makes it clear you handle the edge case.

Comment: Wait, so you aren't happy with `-value` because -INT_MIN is (in unlimited precision math) larger than INT_MAX (and so gives UB). But in that case, what DO you want to be the result of abs(INT_MIN) ? IMO you should just take the first option and accept that `abs(INT_MIN)` is UB, or you should throw an exception of some kind.

Comment: @ChrisBeck, Since `unsigned` can hold it, `-INT_MIN` (mathematically speaking) should presumably be the result.

Comment: @AlexLop. I think this solves my problem! Well, not *exactly* that, but value < 0 ? 0u - unsigned(value) : unsigned(value); seems to work fine - it avoids MSVC warning and is correct AFAICS.

Comment: ah I see, you are casting to unsigned. (missed that before). Yeah why don't you just explicitly handle INT_MIN then, like @chris suggested.

Comment: Explicitly handling INT_MIN does not seem better than ~unsigned(value) + 1 - the latter is faster and both imply 2-complement I think.

Comment: @zeuxcg I think that even without the casting it would do the job. The conversion from signed to unsigned is done automatically by the compiler (if I remember correctly)

Comment: @zeuxcg: is there anything in your question not solved by the solution proposed in the possible duplicate link?

Comment: @zeuxcg, In that case, how about `static_cast<unsigned>(-static_cast<long long>(value))`? You could still argue that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long long)` could be true I guess.

Comment: Yes, solution from the duplicate link is exactly the same as my solution #2 - it produces a warning on MSVC, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @zeuxcg: What is the exact warning produced?

Comment: @chris Yeah, that works, but my *original* problem *also* involves unsigned long long abs(long long) value :)

Comment: @ChrisBeck C4146, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @n.m., NO! Please read the question and the documentation for std::abs more carefully.

Comment: @zeuxcg: why don't you just do `0-unsigned(-value))` then.

Comment: @ChrisBeck yeah, that works as mentioned somewhere above in the comment stream; I did not think of this solution. (presumably you mean unsigned(value))

Comment: i think it's very slightly different from what appeared earlier. the standard completely defines unsigned arithmetic, and defines the conversion of negative signed to unsigned the way you want. explicitly ocnverting to unsigned before `0-` is important, and avoiding `~` is also a good thing. the "real answer" is `-unsigned(value)` like in the original thing that this is a duplicate of. Adding `0` before minus to silence msvc warning is the only thing that's new here.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Yeah, I'm referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676417/how-to-implement-unsigned-absint?noredirect=1#comment53198175_32676417

Comment: @zeuxcg oops... sorry, you are right.

Comment: @zeuxcg - have a look into it. sure it will help [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs) look for 'Compute the integer absolute value (abs) without branching':

Comment: unsigned myabs(int v) { return (v >= 0) ? (unsigned)v : (unsigned)-(v+1)+1; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct approach is #2, but to silence MSVC warning a workaround needs to be applied:

```
unsigned abs(int value) { return value < 0 ? 0 - unsigned(value) : unsigned(value); }
```

The reason this is correct is that signed-to-unsigned conversion is defined to return 2^N+v for negative v; unary minus for unsigned integers is defined as 2^N-v; thus regardless of signed integer representation this code returns the absolute value properly.

Answer (score 1):

If `-value` may result in undefined behavior then this should be well defined:

```
unsigned abs(int value) { return value < 0 ? 0-value : value; }
```